# Integrate Paypal with JSF

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, paypal

I have tried to follow this example and to integrate paypal in a School JSF Project 
Here is the Example : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QsFb7eF5yvI

the Result is not what I expected...

I made a loop over my Shopping Cart and I sent the result to the paypal

[image]
under the Web-INF folder of my application I have created an xml file which contains the authToken of my paypal test Acccount ...

[image]
Once I click on the Button in order to pay I get this error message :

[image]
has Anyone an idea about what I have done wrong , I would be really thankful !

**EDIT !!! Solution :**

In case if someone needs the answer this is the form that we have to submit :

```
<form target="paypal" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr"
        method="post">

        <c:set var="dem" value="1">
        </c:set>


<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="PaulCBeatty@rhyta.com" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1" />

        <c:forEach items="#{productsBean.orderItems}" var="ord">

            <input type="hidden" name="item_number_#{dem}"
                value="#{ord.product.idProduct}" />


            <input type="hidden" name="item_name_#{dem}"
                value="#{ord.product.name}" />


            <input type="hidden" name="quantity_#{dem}" value="#{ord.quantity}" />

            <input type="hidden" name="amount_#{dem}"
                value="#{ord.product.price}" />

            <c:set var="dem" value="#{dem+1}"></c:set>
        </c:forEach>

<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD"/> 
 <input
            type="hidden" name="return" value="http://stackoverflow.com/" /> <input
            type="hidden" name="cancel" value="http://www.google.com" /> 
            <input
            type="image"
            src="http://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_xpressCheckout.gif"></input>
    </form>
```

Comment: It's not clear what role `paypal.xml` plays in this form.

Comment: This is the question ... it's not well explained! I tried to contact the Youtuber and I am still waiting for the answer !

Comment: I won't comment on arbitrary YouTube junk, which is a totally unsuitable medium for conveying information of this kind, but that `paypal.xml` file has nothing to do with this form, and the actual problem was that you didn't do exactly what it said in the video, bvy a considerable margin. You don't need the `dem` variable: you can accompish that via the `varStatus` attribute.

Comment: @user3474488 Can you share the complete code please?